# Can use of special characters in coding be a problem for users somehow?

Tags: html, browser, character-encoding, cross-browser

I have a website with UTF-8 format on all pages.

The website is in Swedish so there are three special characters...

Using these characters in the code (values, ID:s, names etc) works fine on my computer and my browsers, but I wonder if it does work the same on all browsers?

In other words, do you think this will be a problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's OK as long as your application, and other applications that you talk with, know that the text is UTF-8 encoded.

Answer (score 1):

It can be an issue. You'll need to make sure to set the correct character encoding on anything you're sending so the receiving computer will know how to interpret it. There's [a good introduction to character encoding](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) on the Joel On Software blog.